# REST API - Is it allowed to use different representations for POST and PUT/PATCH?

Tags: json, rest

Assume that I have a function for processing POST requests, which takes following representation for POST request:

```html
'
{
  "name": "name",
  "nestedObject": {
    "prop1": "v1",
    "prop2": "v2"
  }
}
'
```

It creates new object with given name and also creates nested object for it with props: prop1 and prop2.

For PUT/PATCH requests however, it would be more convenient for me to use URL of (already existing) object to make it nested object for top-level object, instead passing its data, something like this:

```html
'
{
  "name": "updatedName",
  "nestedObject": "http://alreadyExistingObjectUrl"
}
'
```

GET on the other hand would return nested object data, not its URL:

```html
'
{
  "name": "name",
  "nestedObject": {
    "prop1": "v1",
    "prop2": "v2"
  }
}
'
```

Is it good practice to use different representations of resource for different methods? POST takes nested object data and creates it, PUT/PATCH only takes already existing object url and makes that object nested for parent object. GET returns nested object data, not URL.

Comment: If you are going to use different representations for different actions, it is probably best not to overload the meaning of specific key. That is, if in the case for `PUT`, `"nestedObject"` is going to refer to a url, consider renaming it `"nestedObjectUrl"` to avoid confusion.

Comment: But generally using different representations for different actions is allowed or it should be avoided?

Comment: REST is not a super strict definition, but I agree with @Evert's answer that it is really nice to be able to update your object by making a `PUT` request with the same object you received in your `GET` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a different format, it's a good idea to define specific mimetypes for each.

Generally it's a very good design property to allow a user to do something like:

```
foo = resource.get();
foo.name = 'new name';
resource.put(foo);
```

Basically, if I can assume that the format that `GET` returns can be re-used in a `PUT` request, it also means the server can add new required properties and this will still work.

Anyway, this is a best practice but not a hard recommendation. If the representations of `PUT` and `GET` *are* different I would expect a different mimetype however.

Comment: Basically I wanted PUT/PATCH to take nested object URL representation, and GET to return nested object data. So this it not correct approach. Thank you.